# nextjs page is showing 404 in server but works in localhost

Tags: api, react-hooks, next.js, server, custom-error-pages

This is a React component in Next.js that implements a search functionality. It uses the `useRouter` hook from the `next/router`  library to retrieve the search query from the URL and store it in the `search` variable. Then, the component uses the `useState` hook to store the search results in the `searchData` state.

The component calls an async function `torHeda` in the `useEffect` hook, which sends a `POST` request to the endpoint `domain + 'api/vb1/search-post'`  with the search query in the request body. The response is stored in `resData` , and the `searchData`  state is updated with `resData["data"].`

The component returns a grid of cards with information about the search results, each card is rendered using the `Cards`  component, and the  `title, category_name_bn, created_at, image, id, and status` of each search result is passed as props to the `Cards`  component. If the `searchData`  array is empty, it will return a message indicating that no results were found. It works in localhost perfectly fine but after deploy to server it shows `404 This page could not be found.`

Here is full page code:

```
import Link from 'next/link';
import {useRouter} from 'next/router';
// import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import {useState, useEffect} from "react"
import Cards from '../components/GridCards';
import domain from '../cred';



function SearchDetails() {
    const router = useRouter();
    const search = router.query.search

const [searchData, setSearchData] = useState()
useEffect(()=>{
          
async function torHeda (){
    const data = {
        search: search
    
      }
    
     
      const JSONdata = JSON.stringify(data)
    
      
      const endpoint = domain + 'api/vb1/search-post'
    
    
      const options = {
    
        method: 'POST',
        
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        
        body: JSONdata,
      }
      const response = await fetch(endpoint, options)

      const resData = await response.json();
      const searchData= resData["data"]
      setSearchData(searchData)

}

torHeda()

  },[]);





    return (
        <>
        <div className='grid grid-cols-4 mb-4 gap-10 mx-48 my-12 w-full'> 

{searchData?.map(pageItem=>{
{console.log(searchData)}
            if (searchData !== null) {
                return <Cards key={pageItem?.id} title={pageItem?.title_bn} catagory={pageItem?.category_name_bn} time={pageItem?.created_at} imgSrc={pageItem?.image} status={pageItem?.status}/>;
            }
           
            })}
 
        </div>
                   {(()=>{
                    if(searchData?.length === 0){
                        return <div key={1} className="h-[10rem] flex justify-start items-center mx-48 md:mx-10"> <h1 key={1} className='text-black text-3xl w-full dark:text-white md:text-base'>দুঃখিত আপনি যা খুঁজছেন তা খুঁজে পাওয়া যায়নি! পুনরায় অনুসন্ধান করুণ।</h1> </div>
        
                    }
                })()}</>
    );
}

export default SearchDetails;
```

Answer (score 0):

After deleting this page I build the website using command `npm run build`. After a while I reuploaded the this file and again I rebuild the website.. I tried rebuild many times before but deleing file method worked for me .